# couchdb get session date and query is on veiw

Tags: session, view, couchdb

i want get the session date when it open to get all the record after i open my session not before ,i want something like this

```
function(doc) {
 if (doc.created_at) {
        if session.date => doc.created_at {  
          emit(doc.created_at, doc);
      {
     }
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

I've fallen for this problem myself when I was a couchdb newbie.

You need to understand first, that the map function is not executed when you run the view. The time of execution is only the very first time when the view is called after the document was last updated. And that only if the `stale` parameter was either not used or set to `updateAfter`.

What you can do instead is to use the `startkey` parameter when accessing the view. If you set this to the sessiondate, then only those documents created after the session date will be returned.

You however have to ensure consistent formatting and that the keys will be strictly sorted alphabetically numerically. E.g. by translating them to epoch times or a format in the style of yyyymmdd-ddmmss like 20140618-211259 for the time now (18th of June 2014 @ 21:12:59)

Some examples of the parameters you can use are [here](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options).